# jQuery: Slide animation on DIV changes its size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple HTML page wherein I'm attempting to apply the slide animation on a DIV. The DIV has nothing fancy and is described below:

```
<body>
     <div id="content" style="position:absolute; top: 5%; left: 5%; width:80%; 
                              height:70%; color:#333; background:#eaeaea; 
                              border:1px solid #333;">

          <input type="button" name="buttonId" value="click!"/>

     </div>
</body>
```

Clicking on the button invokes a jQuery animation function to slide this DIV to the right:

```
   $('#content').hide('slide', { direction: 'right' }, 1000);
   $('#content').show('slide', { direction: 'right' }, 500);
```

Now the issue that I'm facing is, when the DIV begins its sliding animation, then there's a clear 'squeezing' of its height. Once the animation completes, the DIV regains its actual height. But through the animation, the DIV's height remains shortened.

I have also observed that when I set the `height` attribute of the DIV using a fixed unit like `px` or `em`, then there's no such squeezing. The distortion only occurs when the height is set in `%`.

Can someone tell me what causes this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You already have the solution to your problem,
Get the outer width of your element and set it to pixels before calling the sliding animation.
Add a callback to the function and set it back to a percentage once the effect has finished animating.

I have no idea why its squeezing.

Comment: well that's correct. but my question is more towards understanding **why** is it like this?

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem and I've solved it by changing width and height by min-width and min-height solved my problem. The difference is that I have the style in css file.